# Hot to get rid of TestFlight error "you're currently installing another version of X. It will be cancelled if you continue"?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

We've been having this problem for some days now. Our QA team can't install our builds from TestFlight in one of our devices.

> "**Install X 1.1.0 (0)?**
>   You're currently installing another version
>   of X. It will be cancelled if you continue"

I've tried to reinstall TestFlight, restart the device, reset all settings, re-invite the user, login with a different user but nothing changes. Do you guys have any more suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Seems you have 2 versions in testing. Cancel all other and try to install again.

Answer (score 0):

The device was running on iOS 10, the only way I could get it installed was after doing an OS update, which was not ideal (as we need to have some older OS versions for testing).

Answer (score 0):

With iExplorer on the Mac, navigate to /Media/Downloads/ on the iPhone and delete all files. After that, reboot and try the installation of the App again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The device was used for development before I tried the Testflight installation.

Deleting the app und rebooting the device did not help.

I installed the app from XCode once more (run on device).
After that, the problem was solved.